# best way to access online database from android app?

Tags: android, database-connection

Building an android social app that allows everyone to share pictures. What's the best practice to display the pictures from an online database to my social app? Would it also be possible to these online db pictures to do a horizontal scroll with imageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the images in your online database in the form of Base64 byte array and then maybe create a web-service which will request for that image from the database.

You easily inter-convert Base64 and Bitmap formats, so the conversion shouldn't be a problem.

When you want to upload any image, convert into a byte array and store it on the database via a web-service. When you want to download any image, get the byte array and convert into Bitmap and display in your application.

Feel free to ask if I failed to be clear.

**EDIT : Creating and Connecting to a Web-service**

Use SQL server to manage the data on your desktop and create a web-service in .Net on Visual Studio.

Then connect to the web-service in your application and set/get data from the DB.

Link on [how to make a web-service in .NET](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx) (does not include the implementation in Android).

Links on how to connect your service with Android :

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Do I need an online webserver running https in order to use web-service?

Comment: Not really, have a look at the edit in my answer. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for all the links that you've provided. These should keep me busy for a while.