# What is the best way to transfer data from an online database into an android app using MicrosoftAzure/similar services?

Tags: android, database, azure

Beginner here,I have tried getting the data using mongoDB driver which proved to be a herculean task as the app crashed every time I tried to create a connection to database.(The queries ran perfectly if executed separately). Then I tried to implement the queries on an asynctask class which ran on a separate thread in android. I feel there is a much simpler way to achieve the task at hand. **The data i am trying to access is required by the UI of the app , so it should be fast.**

I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756243/best-way-to-access-online-database-from-android-app) but how exactly do we go about creating a web service . Can we use a framework like flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please start with the following tutorial. Here is the Xamarin version. There are also other version of this tutorial, depending on the technology stack relevent:

.NET
Node.js
Java
Python

[Build mobile applications with Xamarin and Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mobile-apps-with-xamarin)

[image: Tutorial drop-down list]